# Запрос select на vba

Tags: access, vba, sql

Пишу программку на access, не сильно разбираюсь в vba. Есть загвоздка. Выполняю sql запрос:

```
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT deti FROM deti WHERE rodit NOT IN (SELECT id FROM rodit);")
```

Как проверить, что в результате выполнения данного запроса rs2 не пустой?

Через rs2 Is Empty не получается, выдает:

> `«Run-time error 424»
>   Object required`

Надеюсь на помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Первая ссылка по запросу "RecordSet пустой": [if Form.Recordset = пусто then ...](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=667432)

Ответы оттуда:

```
if MyForm.Recordset.EOF then 
if MyForm.Recordset.RecordCount=0 then
```

Comment: спасибо!
использовал If rs2.RecordCount = 0 Then